# Use environment variable with Postgres initialization script run by docker-composer

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've created a database initialization script that creates the database and adds an entry to a specific table.

```
insert into user (email) values (${USER_EMAIL})
```

My docker-compose file is similar to this one:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:10.5
        restart: always
        environment: 
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        logging:
          options:
            max-size: 10m
            max-file: "3"
        ports:
          - '5438:5432'
        volumes:
          - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
          # copy the sql script to create tables
          - ./sql/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
          # copy the sql script to fill tables
          - ./sql/fill_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fill_tables.sql
```

USER_EMAIL is an env variable is is not being set in the script. What's the right way to do  this?

Answer (score -1):

The `USER_EMAIL` is not going to be available in sql file. I think you already tried that. Try using `envsubst`. So something like

```
command: >
  /bin/bash -c "envsubst < '$USER\_EMAIL' > ./initdb/fill_tables.sql"
```

*I haven't tried pulling that pg image. So not sure if `envsubst` is available inside.*

Comment: I am getting this error: "/bin/bash: : No such file or directory"

Comment: That means bash is not available in the underlying image.. try `sh`

Comment: Complete example [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/o4yjhh/use_environment_variable_with_postgres/)

Answer (score -2):

if you want to give a value for USER_EMAIL, you can simply add it in environment section.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:10.5
        restart: always
        environment: 
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
          - USER_EMAIL
        logging:
          options:
            max-size: 10m
            max-file: "3"
        ports:
          - '5438:5432'
        volumes:
          - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
          # copy the sql script to create tables
          - ./sql/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
          # copy the sql script to fill tables
          - ./sql/fill_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fill_tables.sql
```

in your script just set a value for USER_EMAIL.